# Корень в слове косяк

Tags: корень-слова

Какой корень в слове косяк (птиц)? Кос- или косяк?

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего, при разборе слова по составу следует выделить корень КОС, но это решение не совсем очевидно.

С одной стороны, слово "косяк" не входит непосредственно в словообразовательное гнездо прилагательного "косой" (словарь такую связь не фиксирует). С другой стороны, составляющие его морфемы узнаваемы и продуктивны в современном языке, и мы можем выделить их: корень КОС в слове "косой" - расположенный под углом к горизонту, поверхности, не отвесный; суффикс ЯК со значением предмета, обладающего данным признаком (ср. кругляк, сорняк).

НЕМНОГО ИСТОРИИ

Косяк - исконно русское слово, название по форме косого угла фигуры стада животных или стаи птиц.

Однако и само слово "косой" появилось в языке не так давно (в источниках известно только с конца 16 века)и тоже имеет интересную этимологию.

И.-е. корень "kes", о.-с. корень  "cesati" -чесать, рвать, скрести, теребить.  Возможное значение с о.-с. поры -  "срезанный под углом" с помощью "косы" - длинного кривого ножа. В то же время "коса" (сельскохоз.) соотносится и с лат. castrare -  резать тоже с о.-с. времени.

"Коса" - женские волосы также общесл. - то, что расчесывается.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, "кос-".

"Косяк" все равно связан с "косить", "косой".

Answer (score 2):

Верно!Корень -  кос , суффикс - як. Этимологию см.здесь. http://enc-dic.com/rusethy/Kosjak-1359.html